# How do I determine if a nucleophile attacks the electrophilic atom directly or indirectly?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solutions, nucleophilic-substitution

How do I determine if a nucleophile attacks the electrophilic atom directly or indirectly? For instance a nucleophile could attack the carbon in a molecule with a carbonyl directly, but in another example the nucleophile might only attack the nucleophilic atom after attacking a hydrogen first (deprotonation). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hard-Soft Acid-Base Theory provides rules of thumb to predict which electrophilic atom a given nucleophile will attack. But pattern recognition/memorization is also useful.

Comment: Ultimately only experimental data is definative. One can make predictions but until they are backed by experiment they remain "best gueses".